# Getting column ambiguously defined when I shouldn't. Why?

Tags: oracle, with-statement, union-all, ambiguous

I have two tables that return results when I put them together using `UNION ALL`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
```

But for some reason when I add this code into a `WITH` clause, like below, it does not work:

```
WITH            
SQ_Union AS
(
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    SQ_Union
```

When I run that I get the following:

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

Both tables have the same columns, name the same, but with differing table names, and data content. Why does this run without the `WITH` clause, and not run with it?

Comment: ther'es only one table `TABLE_A` in your sample and the query works fine. can you check you query and provide the sql that is not working?

Comment: The error message should point to specific line in the code, please provide that info as well.

Answer (score 1):

I created the tables this way on purpose.

```
create table a (a1 number, b1 number);
create table b (b1 number, a1 number);

insert into a values (1, 2);
insert into b values (3, 4);
commit;

WITH            
   SQ_Union AS (
      SELECT * FROM a
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT * FROM b
   )
SELECT * FROM SQ_Union;
```

I cannot make this fail on Oracle 12.1.0.2. I suspect you have a problem with code that you haven't shared.

BTW, the above text would be considered an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When *you* make an attempt to create one, you'll no doubt find the cause of the problem. To quote one of my favorite characters, "Take it slow".